# Displaying a GIF in Silverlight

Tags: image, silverlight, gif, imagesource

I have a number of gifs in a folder on my web server `/dir/subdir/bla.gif` etc.

On that same server is a Silverlight 3 application `/ClientBin/bla.xap`.

Is there any way to display the gifs in the Silverlight app?

I've tried `<Image x:Name=img" />` and then in code setting `this.img.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/dir/subdir/bla.gif"))` with no success.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: I've finally create Gif Control for Silverlight using GifDecoder 3d Library wich was design for windows forms application in C#, orginal was in java
and i've make modification to it so it can work with silverlight. And then i create a custom Usercontrol. https://gifsilverlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might look into Silverlight ImageTools on Codeplex: http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

> ### Project Description
>
> ImageTools for Silverlight is a library, which provides additional
> functionality for loading, saving and manipulation images from
> different sources and with different formats.
>
> At the moment the library is able to load the most important png, jpg,
> bmp and gif formats. Please have a look at the following demo and
> select a image which should be displayed. If an error messages appears
> this means, that the file is not supported yet and I would very happy
> for a comment with the image attached, which you used for testing.

Answer (score 4):

Silverlight does not natively support GIF.  If you want to spend some money, you can buy a third party control, such as this one: http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ImageSilverlight/