# Is there any single way to show all types of Images on WP7

Tags: image, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am working on a WP7.5 application where I have to download multiple images
and show them in a list.
The images may be PNG, JPEG, or GIF.
For the first two extensions its not a problem, but as we know,
to show/play a GIF image on WP7, there are some other libraries or controls.
(I tried using ImageTools http://imagetools.codeplex.com/; and it worked fine.
But the control it provide cannot render images other than GIF (or may be I didn't found the way).

Is there any tool or custom control or API which can render all types of images, so that no matter what extension it is, the image is showed?

Comment: What other extensions would you need, for example?

Comment: i want to show gif, png, bmp, jpg images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP7 uses silverlight and silverlight doesn't support GIF images.

Please check these links for information regarding the same. http://forums.silverlight.net/p/39235/112333.aspx

and you may also find some useful answers to your question here: [Displaying a GIF in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457959/displaying-a-gif-in-silverlight)